# wxWidgets and logging

Tags: wxwidgets

I cannot redirect log messages when building GUI applications in wxWidgets. I've tried the following snippet

```
delete wxLog::SetActiveTarget(new wxLogStderr()) ;
```

so that every call to wxLogXXX would cause a message to be print in the standard error output, not as a message dialog presented to the user. However, it had no effect, and logs continue to be present as dialog messages.

Am I missing something?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the delete.  Simply call SetActiveTarget

```
wxLog::SetActiveTarget(new wxLogStderr()) ;
```

Here's what it looks like in my IDE ( VS2008 )

[image]

Comment: You do need to either delete the returned pointer or store it and call `SetActiveTarget()` with it later to restore it (and you need to delete your own target in this case, of course), otherwise you have a memory leak.

And in any case deleting or not the returned pointer shouldn't change the behaviour of the new target so the OP has some other problem.